# Expand top of scale/axis to include text

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to annotate the highest value in each facet of a graph.

I can't figure out how to remove extra space at the bottom of the y axis without clipping the text above the highest value.

A) Is there a non-symmetrical version of `scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))`?

B) Or, is there a way to make ggplot include text as part of the graph range?

```
# a simple dataset
count <- 40
data <- data.frame(
  category = sample(LETTERS[1:3], count, TRUE),
  x = rnorm(count),
  y = abs(rnorm(count))
)

# find the highest value in each category
require(plyr)
data <- data[order(-data$y),]
topValues <- ddply(data, .(category), head, 1)

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_text(data=topValues, aes(x=x, y=y, label=y)) + # label the highest y value
  # add vjust=-1 to put text above point if possible
  facet_grid(category ~ ., scale="free") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: try adding a `geom_blank` layer with the coordinates of topValues slightly scaled up

Comment: @baptiste That did it! Thank you! `geom_blank(data=topValues, aes(x=x, y=y*1.1, label=y))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer comes thanks to [baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937311/expand-top-of-scale-axis-to-include-text/20937617#comment31442078_20937311).

Just add this call to the plot to make a blank point at the top of the text:

```
geom_blank(data=topValues, aes(x=x, y=y*1.1, label=y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vjust` argument of `geom_text` to tweak the vertical position of the label relative to the `x` and `y` coordinate:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_text(data=topValues, aes(x=x, y=y, label=y), vjust = 1.5) + # label the highest y value
  facet_grid(category ~ ., scale="free") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried vjust earlier. I specifically want to the text above the point (vjust=-1) for legibility, but then it completely goes off the edge of the plot.